# Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier - Doesn't Rollback the transaction

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, rollback

The actual issue is not this - "Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier" but the issue is that, the transaction doesn't get rolled back after you hit the issue.

My code here,

```
var connectionstring = "Server= ****; Database= ****; Integrated Security=True;";
        var errorInformation = new List<string>();

        using (SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
        {
            objConn.Open();
            var objTrans = objConn.BeginTransaction(); // Begins here
            var sql = $"insert into tblProject values('7', 'TestProject')";
            SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, objConn, objTrans);

            try
            {
                insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                // ProjectID is a unique Identifier in database
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM SOMEOTHERTABLE WHERE PROJECTID=''", objConn, objTrans);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                var dataTable = new DataTable("SomeTableName");
                using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    var dt = adapter.Fill(dataTable); // Exception happens here
                }
                objTrans.Commit(); // Commit here
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                errorInformation.Add(ex.Message);
            }
            var sql1 = $"insert into tblProject values('8', 'TestProject')";
            SqlCommand objCmd2 = new SqlCommand(sql1, objConn, objTrans);
            objCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (errorInformation.Any())
            {
                objTrans.Rollback(); // Rollback here
            }
        }
```

The query that gets executed after the exception, using the same connection object will not rollback. This is a bug that Microsoft needs to look into. Otherwise their rollback feature is not reliable.

I would expect either my second insert command to fail or my rollback to be successful.

Comment: Check SET XACT_ABORT

Comment: Transactions should be used with a `using` block. Otherwise an exception in the *second* command will bypass the `objTrans.Rollback()` call. In fact, *any* error outside that `try/catch` block will leave the transaction dangling until the GC kicks in and collects it

Comment: BTW that's a serious bug in this code, not a bug in ADO.NET

Comment: @Panagiotis: Even so, the GC should collect the transaction object and it should automatically be rolled back. The only way I can think of the transaction being committed by default is because of IMPLICIT TRANSACTIONS on the connection, which would auto commit the outer transaction?

Comment: @Naveen: can you confirm if the "implicit transactions" in the Instance > Connections settings is switched on?

Comment: @Allumearz, implicit transactions is not enabled in the Sql Instance

Comment: @DaveBrown, Thanks. XACT_ABORT didn't help either.

Comment: @Naveen: ... And you are saying that the second insert works too? Because that should never be the case, as you never commit the transaction... Just out of interest, what happens if you explicitly execute SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF as the first query after opening the connection?

Comment: No it wouldn't have helped once I checked the code - see the comments from @PanagiotisKanavos. XACT_ABORT is a setting that can be used to kill an entire transaction if one single statement fails. With it set OFF, 20 separate inserts within a single transaction with, say a duplicate key in insert number 15 would result in 19 inserts being done. With it ON, no inserts are done.